# getCurrentUser.put() not updating parse user object

Tags: android, parse-platform

So I'm trying to implement leaderboard for the android game I'm making. I want to store high scores in my user objects after they play the game, but when I use the put method, it does not seem to update my user objects on Parse.

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null){
            user.put("DailyScore",score);
        }
```

When I print user.get("DailyScore"), it prints the score which it supposedly had just saved, but when I view the user on Parse it still has no updated information for DailyScore.

Comment: Are you calling user.saveInBackground()?

Comment: No I am not. Dumb mistake on my part. Thanks!

Comment: It happens to everyone, haha ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are never saving the user object to the server so your changes are only local. Call `saveInBackground()` on the user object and it will be saved to the server.

Comment: Wow, dumb mistake on my part. Thanks!